# Styling issue with a telerik control on published page

Tags: asp.net, css, telerik, styling

When debugging offline, I have a page that is displayed correctly. However, when viewing the published page the styling is all off on all telerik RadNumericTextBox's. By styling - I mean positioning. Please see the screenshot below:

[image]

The boxes overflow the scrolling area and so are not affected by the scrolling at all.

These RadNumericTextBox's are part of a repeater's body:

```
          <td>
                    <telerik:RadNumericTextBox runat="server" ID="txtUnitPrice" Text='<%# Bind("UnitPrice") %>'>
                        <ClientEvents OnValueChanged="txtValueChanged" />
                    </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
                </td>
```

No styling is applied inline as you can see. However, the following is rendered (obviously some sort of web resource is applying the styles):

```
<span class="riDisplay" id="ctl00_MainContent_Edit1_rptTasks_ctl03_txtQtyOrdered_display" style="width: 148px; text-align: left; color: #000; line-height: normal; padding-right: 5px; padding-left: 5px; font-family: "segoe ui",arial,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; border-right-width: 3px; border-left-width: 1px; display: inline;" _events="[object Object]">
```

Can anyone shed any light on this please? Both offline and 'online' versions are running in the same browser mode.

EDIT: Something quite strange has just happened - I've reloaded the page, opened developer tools back up and looked into the exact same element, and the following is now showing as what is rendered:

```
<span class="riDisplay" id="ctl00_MainContent_Edit1_rptTasks_ctl03_txtQtyOrdered_display" style="display: none;"/>
```

It's still not displaying right - but it seems weird that it's been rendered twice differently.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about the control your using but I'd try wrapping a function around your onValueChanged event first.

```
<ClientEvents OnValueChanged="function(s,e){txtValueChanged();)" />
```

Then I'd get out firebug (via firefox) and see what styles your control is using and make sure their loaded before anything else. Would need to see what CSS Classes/Styles to more help beyond that.